# Hard ODE: $x^2(y')^2+3xyy'+2y^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2(y')^2+3xyy'+2y^2=0$$
I have no idea how to start, I probably need to do some tricky substitution but as of now I cant see any options.

Answer (score 15):

It factors as $$(xy'+2y)(xy'+y)=0.$$ Now solve each equation separately.

Comment: Ah, thank you, too bad I didnt even consider such an easy way to think of it.

Comment: Nice answer! (y)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
\Big( x y' + \frac{3}{2} y \Big)^2 = x^2 (y')^2 + 3xy y' + \frac{9}{4} y^2
$$